# The type javax.validation.Payload cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am using eclipse to try to run a simple project [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/). When I typed contents in eclipse, it says: `The type javax.validation.Payload cannot be resolved`. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class` files. In the example shown there, he used `maven` and in my practice I haven't.

I also have maven plugin in eclipse `m2e-wtp` latest and `kepler` version of eclipse. I tried many websites, such as [this one](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-dynamic-web-project-maven-eclipse-wtp/). Here he used command window and used some commands, but when I tried in my pc, it didn't work. I think maven needs to set in my environment variable. That means I have to install maven in my `c:/programfiles` or any.

Is there a way to run the commands in eclipse(naive)? can some one give me a link to build sample maven project using `m2e eclipse`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I downloaded the application, and it ran fine on my computer.
All I did was unzip and type:

```
mvn clean tomcat:run-war
```

I think you might be missing a [transitive dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) (which Maven will automatically download), ensure you have all of these on your eclipse classpath:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringMVC Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ SpringMVC ---
[INFO] com.mkyong.common:SpringMVC:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.132s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 04 22:07:24 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My guess is this jar:

```
javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
```

Comment: i am not using maven so the command you given wont work. i manually included all the jars. and yes "The type javax.validation.Payload cannot be resolved" is solved by adding validation-api.jar file.